# How to cache complex calculated temporary Data

Tags: symfony, caching, redis, memcached, varnish

I have an Application that allows people to bet on the result of soccer games.
The score of each single bet (=entity) is calculated by comparing the betted scores of the bet with the actual result in the game(=entity). Bet's are betted within Betrounds. Betrounds are organisations where groups bet on gamegroups (groups of games e.g. single matchdays). Single Usergroups can have several betrounds.

To summarize the relational model:
UserGroup 1:N BetRounds 1:N Bets N:1 Game

Within each betround I create a resulttable where I show every user with their result points and position. 
In order to calculate the position of one user I need to calculate the points of every user within a betround.
These points from the single betrounds are aggregated into  groups and within the group there is again a resulttable.

**Example**

- A Usergroup with: 20 users
- One Season has 34 matchdays
- One matchday has 9 games

In order to calculate the the points for this usergroup I would need to calculate the points from 20*34*9=6120 bets.

Since this is a lot to calculate I don't want to do it everytime I show the resulttable.
I currently see two options in order to save some calculation time:

1. Cache
2. Save interim results (e.g. on the bet entity) in the database
3. Maybe a mix of both.

> 1. Cache

If caching is the correct way I am not sure on which level and how to invalidate.
There are several options what to cache:
- pointresult of single bets
- pointresults of single users within a betround
- whole result table of a betround (points & position)
- pointresult of single user within usergroup
- whole resulttable of usergroup

I am unsure how to cache those data:
- just the integer values for positions and points
- whole entities (e.g. bets)
- temporary not persistent entities (e.g. to represent the the resulttables)
- the html output of the table

Then dependent on format how to cache it:
- html views could be cached via reverse proxies
- values / entities probably via redis / memcache etc.

In the future we might change to a single page app that data is only served via restapi, then caching of html outputs is not an option.

Dependent on the caching strategy the question arises how to invalidate cache and optionally warm it, so that the result is never calculated within the application but only recalculated when the cache is invalidated and immediately replaced by the new result.

I have read very often that cache invalidation is evil. I am not sure if this applies to my use case since all points/results/tables etc. only change when my interface updates the result of the games. This is the only time when points change.

> 2.Save interim results (e.g. on the bet entity) in the database

I am not sure if this scenario is applicable on all levels. I first thought about saving the actual result on a bet instead of always comparing the bet scores with the actual scores. This would then make my data model a little bit redundent and i have increased complexity if I wrong result is fetched by my interface and later the correct comes in and my points are not recalculated.

On all other levels I would need to create new interim entities to store table results persistently.

> 3.Mix of both

I am not sure how mixing both would look like and if it makes sense at all, but I thought it might be an option.

Any advice, Input or experience would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I only mildly understand betting, so hopefully this helps.

It sounds like you are asking two questions:

1. When do I calculate results?
2. How much caching should I use?

To me it sounds like there are very clear events that happen, after which you can successfully calculate your results. Your design should take advantage of this and be evented in nature. You should have background processes that can detect when a game is complete. The results of the game should be written, and additional background jobs should be triggered to calculate the results of any bets that depend on that game.

This would also be the point at which any caches that involve that game, results from that game, or results from any bets on that game, should be invalidated and/or refreshed.

How much you should cache should be based on how much you need to cache. Caching should be considered separately from computing results. That is not caching. That is computing results and storing them. You should definitely not be calculating results during a page view request, and should be done ahead of time when the corresponding event (game ends) has triggered the calculation.

Your database should pretty much always represent the latest information you have on everything. You should avoid doing any calculations on-the-fly if possible.

I would get all the events and background stuff working first, then see what kind of performance you get. At that point your app should be doing little more than taking the results and sticking them into a view for each page view. If that part is going too slow, then you should start looking at caching your views/templates/html. As mentioned before, these caches could be invalidated by your background workers when they encounter new results.

Comment: Hi, so for me this means to save the betpoint result in the database and update that value if the underlying game changes. All tables should not be stored but only the output should be cached (So only the partial view, NOT the raw data and then rerendered). This means I can use something like the https://github.com/asm89/twig-cache-extension for it or Varnish with edge side includes. Unfortunately my cloud provider does not yet offer varnish. So I will probably go with cache blogs in twig.